# unable to restart or update a timer

Tags: elisp, time-date

I have simple timer which makes sure a function is executed for every 10 seconds.

```
(setq interval 10)

(defun run-every-ten-seconds ()
    (do-something))

(defun start-timer ()
  (setq timer
    (run-at-time (current-time)  interval
                 'run-every-ten-seconds))))
```

Everything works fine.

Now instead of saving it for every 10 seconds, i want to increment 1 second every time it saves. So i need to save it after 10 seconds, then 11 seconds, 12 seconds and so on.

But when I try to cancel & start a new timer with the function, it is getting into infinite loop.

```
(defun run-every-ten-seconds ()
    (do-something)
    (cancel-timer timer) 
    (setq interval (1+ interval))
    (setq timer
      (run-at-time (current-time)  interval
                   'run-every-ten-seconds)))
```

Any ideas to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is saying `run-at-time NOW`, and passing *itself* as the callback.

I think you want `(run-at-time interval nil ...)`, and you doubtless won't need to cancel a non-repeating timer which has already triggered.

Comment: thank you. i was looking if there is any function update timer.

Answer (score 0):

i ended up using `time-add`, `seconds-to-time` to modify the time interval

```
(run-at-time
 (time-add (current-time) (seconds-to-time interval))
   interval 'run-every-ten-seconds)))
```

Comment: That's the same result as `(run-at-time interval interval)` (and if the interval isn't going to be consistent, then I think you ought to be using `interval nil`, as I had suggested -- a repeating timer which you always cancel before the second iteration shouldn't be a repeating timer).